# I’m trying to calculate cosine by using Maclaurin series in c++, but the results of my code aren’t as results of function cos().

Tags: c++

for example when the input is 30 ; out put of cos() is 
0.866025 and out put of my code is 
0.46386.

also the loop doesn’t end when the input is 60 or more. i don’t know where is the error.
what should i do to fix it?

```
int main()
{double deg;
int num;
cin>>deg;
double x=deg*3.141592654/180;
double term=0;
double cur=x;   current term
double result=x;
double s=cos(x);
cout<<s<<endl;

for(int n=0;;n++){
term=cur*(-x*x/(2*n+2)*(2*n+1));

if(abs(term-cur)< eps){
    cout << result << endl;
return 0;
}
  else{
     result+=term;
     cur=term;
  }


}
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now is probably a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This code doesn't compile.  Please [edit] it to reflect the actual, complete code that you're asking about.

Comment: A way to check that your implementation is correct, particularly with such a small program, is to trace through with paper and pencil the calculations of your variables at each step. That way you can determine where you went wrong. Double check your equation to start with.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed couple of errors.

1. The first term of the series needs to be 1.0, not x.

   ```
   double cur = 1.0;
   double result = cur;
   ```
2. The expression used to calculate the next term is incorrect.

   ```
   cur*(-x*x/(2*n+2)*(2*n+1));
   ```

   is incorrect because the last part of that expression, `*(2*n+1)`, becomes a multiplier instead of a divisor due to operator associativity. Change that to:

   ```
   cur * (-x*x) / ((2*n+2)*(2*n+1));
   ```

I think it will be better to move the code to compute the cosine to a function of its own.

```
double mycos(double x)
{
   double eps = 1.0e-10;
   double cur = 1.0;//   current term
   double result = cur;

   for(int n=0;;n++){
      int divisor = (2*n + 1)*(2*n + 2);
      double term = cur*(-x*x)/divisor;

      if(std::fabs(term-cur) < eps){
         break;
      }
      result += term;
      cur = term;
   }

   return result;
}
```

Then, you can use

```
std::cout << mycos(x) << std::endl;
```

from `main`.